# Trouble loading predis on php website

Tags: php, redis, predis

**Answer:**
I had to change the path of PREDIS_BASE_PATH to predis/lib/.

I want to load predis inside of a PHP file, but I am having trouble. I am following the guide to load predis on the predis github website (https://github.com/nrk/predis).
Here is the code that I am using to load predis:

```
define("PREDIS_BASE_PATH", "predis/");
echo "The predis base path is: " . PREDIS_BASE_PATH . "\n";
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
  $file = PREDIS_BASE_PATH . strtr($class, '\\', '/') . '.php';
  echo "The file variable is: " . $file . "\n";
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    require $file;
    return true;
  }
});

$redis = new Predis\Client(array(
  'host'  => 'localhost',
  'port'  => 6379,
));
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Predis\Client' not found
```

Edit: What file in the predis directory should be imported? After changing the folder permissions, I am able to echo what the variable $file is holding: "The file variable is: predis/Predis/Client.php"

According to the directory listing here, https://github.com/nrk/predis, there is no client.php file.

Comment: as the error says, the class is not in the current scope. sure $file is correct?

Answer (score 13):

I use below code to connect predis on php page, and it worked fine.. below is code

```
<?php
        require "predis/autoloader.php";
        Predis\Autoloader::register();

        $redis = new Predis\Client(array(
         "scheme" => "tcp",
         "host" => "127.0.0.1",
         "port" => 6379));
?>
```

Comment: Why there is instance twice,  $redis = new Predis\Client();
        $redis = new Predis\Client(array(...

Answer (score 3):

write the below code to call the register method:

```
Predis\Autoloader::register();
```

instead of `PredisAutoloader::register();`

And put your test file parallel to Predis Folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
$redis = new Predis\Client(array(
```

should be

```
$redis = new Predis_Client(array(
```

Comment: Yes, but that does not work. If you look in the code of Predis.php, there is no class Predis\Client, but there is Predis_Client. It is an error that has gotten me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I used composer to install Redis and got a but of hard time making it work. Eventually the following script worked.

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
echo "Root ".dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
require_once(__ROOT__.'/vendor/autoload.php');//load all PHP dependencies
//require_once(__ROOT__.'/vendor/predis/predis/autoload.php'); //load only Redis also works
$REDIS_SERVER="127.0.0.1";
$REDIS_PORT=6379;
try 
{
    echo "<p>Connecting to Redis $REDIS_SERVER:$REDIS_PORT";

    $redis = new Predis\Client(array(
        "scheme" => "tcp",
        "host" => $REDIS_SERVER,
        "port" => $REDIS_PORT
    ));
    echo "<p>Hello I am Redis";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfectly fine. I can only assume that you aren't importing the class correctly. Are you sure $file is where the code is assuming it is.

Double check it's there and set the permissions to 777 using `sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/file` and see if that works.

Reset the permissions to something more secure afterwards if it works/doesn't work.

Hope this helps

**EDIT:**

Download Predis.php, put it in the same directory as the file with your php code in it, and make the code look like this:

```
  spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
  $file =  strtr($class, '\\', '/') . '.php';
  echo "The file variable is: " . $file . "\n";
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    require $file;
    return true;
  }
});

$redis = new Predis\Client(array(
  'host'  => 'localhost',
  'port'  => 6379,
));
```

Comment: Which file should be imported?

Comment: Predis.php is the file required

Comment: Where can the predis.php file be located? I am looking in the predis/lib directory, but I cannot find it.